# insert 0 rows without error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can an insert ever execute without error but not insert anything?  I am using sql server 2008 and wondering if I can get away with just checking `@@error` or is there something I am missing.  For an update I check `@@error` and `@@rowcount`.  Having `@@rowcount = 0` for an insert just seems strange to me.

*edit*
@Gregory  I basically wondering how I should error check an insert statement.  Are there any strange boundary cases where an insert execute and `@@error` is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run an `INSERT` command using a select that returns an empty table.

The statement will succeed but no rows updated.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM myOtherTable
WHERE 1 = 2
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a mouse-click. :) +1

Comment: @Ken - Sorry - will try to be slower next time ;)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.  Am I safe checking `@@error` if use values i.e.`    insert into test(aCol)    values(42)`  ?

Comment: @Rico - See the answer by @HLGEM, as this is not the only situation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you experiencing no errors, but no insert?

Or is this just a question on why you should use ROWCOUNT? ROWCOUNT has other purposes than checking whether or not a single insert worked.

Or are you asking about @@ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, an insert could end up inserting no rows without an error if there is an instead of trigger involved.